# Are there rules to create new special maneuvers?

Tags: street-fighter-rpg

I have not found rules for creating new special maneuvers in Street Fighter RPG. Is there an official book that has rules for this?

Comment: Today I learned that there's a Street Fighter RPG.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The system does not give any rules on how to create new moves.**  Instead, the list of moves that exist to be selected from is intended to be exhaustive and balanced, and any attempt at creating a "new" move is done by **re-skinning an existing move** with your own name and flavor while remaining mechanically the same.  The book justifies this with examples, such as explaining that Guile's *Sonic Boom* and Dee Jay's *Air Slasher* are essentially the same move.

The [20th Anniversary Edition](http://sfrpg.com/wp-content/uploads/Street-Fighter-TSG-20th-Anniversary.pdf) is a fan-community-made compilation and rebalance-mod of all the moves and mechanics from all of the supplemental books, as well as fan creations from the newer entries in the video game series (such as characters from Street Fighters 3, 4, and 5), and should have a **higher quantity and quality of moves to select from** compared to the original version.

Comment: This is a good answer and pretty much what I would've said; the only thing I'd suggest is adding that several new special maneuvers were added in the supplemental books like The Perfect Warrior and Contenders.

Comment: @JohnClifford I mentioned that the Anniversary Edition compiles such changes.  What else would be missing?

Comment: I missed the part about the compilation being from all the supplemental books, I thought it only mentioned the original sourcebook. It's fine as-is, so I gave you an upvote.